# How to access a directory in docker container from host machine?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a docker wildFly container running on 127.0.0.1:8089 in my host. I would like to make this as my default application server for testng/arquilian test.

```
Earlier : -DWILDFLY_HOME=/Users/abdulrazak/dev/wildfly/devsetup/wildfly-8.1.0.Final
```

I was using wildfly instance on my local as a default and I would to change this to docker wildlfy instance.

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                              NAMES
70eb157707ac        my_test_wildfly     "container-entrypo..."   26 minutes ago      Up 28 minutes       9990/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8090->8080/tcp   vibrant_cori
```

How can I point wildFly directory on docker container as my WILDFLY_HOME path ?

Answer (score 2):

From what I understand, you want to make the wildfly home on your machine accessible by the container. For that you can bind your wildfly directory on your host onto the container.

```
docker run -v <path-to-folder-on-host>:<path-in-container> ...
```

This will mount the folder on the machine onto the container at the specified location.